# add string to first item in list of list of strings in python

Tags: python, list

Sorry for the title but I believe it is what I am trying to do.

So I have a list of lists.  Each item in the sublist is a time and a number. such as...

```
[['01:16:01 PM', '80.31'], ['01:17:01 PM', '80.32'], ['01:18:01 PM', '80.30'], ['01:19:01 PM', '80.30'], ['01:20:01 PM', '80.30'], ['01:21:01 PM', '80.32'], ['01:22:01 PM', '80.32'], ['01:23:01 PM', '80.31'], ['01:24:01 PM', '80.41'], ['01:25:01 PM', '80.38']]
```

I want to add the date to each element in the list before(or after) the time element. So...
date="2012-09-15"

So each element would be like so

```
[['2012-09-15 01:16:01 PM', '80.31'], ['2012-09-15 01:17:01 PM', '80.32']... etc]
```

I have been googling but have not found a solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the Python tutorial. All the information you need is in the section on [strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and the section on [lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Also, it would be great if you could say what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myList = [['01:16:01 PM', '80.31'], ['01:17:01 PM', '80.32'], ['01:18:01 PM', '80.30']]
updateList =  [ ["2012-09-15 "+x[0], x[1]] for x in myList]
```

Leads to:

```
[['2012-09-15 01:16:01 PM', '80.31'],
['2012-09-15 01:17:01 PM', '80.32'],
['2012-09-15 01:18:01 PM', '80.30']]
```